# Zero padding : convert MD-1 to MD-001 with pure sql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

guys I need help.

I am using Mysql / phpmyadim.

I have db with table which stores name and code id of people.

```
+--------+---------+
| Name   | code_id |
+--------+---------+
| Nazeer | MD-1    |
+--------+---------+
```

I have 10 contacts and ids. I am using php program which used to generate automatic code.

recently i imported more records in to db from excel file and record increase to 5000+.

My php automatic code stopped generating codes giving me syntax error on code id.

I figured out that my excel import was having code id like MD-1, MD-2, etc.  and my program used automatic code for number in 3 digits since my record is over thousands which 4 digit it give syntax error.

I did some research on solving that and the answer was to change all 2 digit numbers eg. "MD-1" ~ "MD-99" TO "MD-001" ~ "MD-099" and my program will work again.

so the question is how do i do that in phpmyadmin sql to change it.  I need to keep 'MD-' and add '0' then add back the corresponding number.

thanks and appreciate your help in advance.

Regrds.

Comment: hi, it shouldn't be too hard to pad zeros into your data, but the point I'd like to make is that your php script seems to be very unscalable. If simply adding entries will break your script, what if you need to add 10000 entries a few days later? add another zero to those data? I'd suggest you to actually change your focus and ask for help to fix your PHP script so it can support any number of digits instead of changing your data to fit your script. (post your php code if possible)

Comment: I suspect that you're perfectly capable of identifying the obvious flaw in this design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sql will update all your data, but like I said in comments, you better off fixing your php code instead.

WARNING : this sql only works assuming all your data are in the format of [MD-xxx] with 3 or less numbers in it

```
UPDATE your_table SET 
    code_id=case length(substr(code_id,4)) 
        WHEN 1 THEN concat("MD-00",substr(code_id,4)) 
        WHEN 2 THEN concat("MD-0",substr(code_id,4)) 
        ELSE code_id END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to update the content MD-1 to MD-001 and MD-99 to MD-099. To do that you can write a PHP code to retrieve the rows one by one and have to match patterns and then update. Here are some useful links. [link 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm) 
HINT : you can check 5 digit string and then add another 0 in the position of 3.(use [exploid] to split by "-" and then concat with "-0" [2](http://www.php.net/explode)) There are no way to do the same only by using MYSQl since it's not a programming language. And other thing is PHP is not a program. It's a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

run UPDATE query and use CONCAT function :

```
 for ($x=0; $x=<upto>; $x++){
    UPDATE <table_name>
    SET <columnname>= CONCAT('MD-',0,$x) 
    WHERE <columnname>= CONCAT('MD-',$x)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below simple update command can help you.

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET code_id=IF(LENGTH(code_id)=4,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(code_id,'-',1),'-00',SUBSTRING_INDEX(code_id,'-',-1)),IF(LENGTH(code_id)=5,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(code_id,'-',1),'-0',SUBSTRING_INDEX(code_id,'-',-1)),code_id));
```